# How do I grab user input after an @ symbol and before a space?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to grab the user input from an input tag including everything after the @ symbol and up to a space if the space exists. For example:

If the user input is "hello@yourname"

I want to grab "yourname"

If the user input is "hello@yourname hisname"

I want to grab "yourname" because it is after the @ symbol and ends at the space.

I have some code written that attempts to grab the user input based on these rules, but there is a bug present that I can't figure out how to fix. Right now if I type "hello@yourname hisname"

My code will return "yourname hisn"

I don't know why the space and four characters "hisn" are being returned. Please help me figure out where the bug is.

Here is my function which performs the user input extraction.

```
 handleSearch(event) {
    let rawName, nameToSearch;
    rawName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();


    if (rawName.indexOf('@') >= 0 && rawName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {

      nameToSearch = rawName.substr(rawName.indexOf('@') + 1, rawName.indexOf(' ') - 1);

    } else if (rawName.indexOf('@') >= 0  && rawName.indexOf(' ') < 0) {

      nameToSearch = rawName.substr(rawName.indexOf('@') + 1);

    } else {

      nameToSearch = '';

    }

    return nameToSearch;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
handleSearch(event) {
    let rawName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (rawName.indexOf("@") === -1) {
      return '';
    }
    return (rawName.split("@")[1].split(" "))[0];
}
```

You have to handle a lack of "@", but you don't need to handle the case where there is a space or not after the "@".  The split function will still behave correctly in either of those scenarios.

Edit:  The specific reason why OP's code doesn't work is because the substr method's second argument is not the end index, but the number of characters to return after the start index.  You can use the similar SUBSTRING method instead of SUBSTR to make this easier.  Change the line after the first if statement as follows:

```
nameToSearch = rawName.substring(rawName.indexOf('@') + 1, rawName.indexOf(' '));
```

Comment: You are correct, it is the difference between the parameters of substr versus substring!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this--

```js
var string = "me@somename yourname";
  var parts = string.split("@");
  var parts2 = parts[1];
var yourPart = parts2.split(" ");
 console.log(yourPart[0]);
```

**NOTE:** 
I am suggesting it just because you know your string structure.

**Suggestion**

For your Piece of code I think you have some white space after `hisn` that is why it is returning this output. Try to replace all the white spaces with some character see if you are getting any white space after `hisn`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const testCases = [
  "hello@yourname",
  "hello@yourname hisname"
];

for (let test of testCases) {
  let re = /@(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
  let result = re.exec(test);
  console.log(result[1]);
}
```

Use regex instead if you know how the string will be created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the language your code is in (there are several it 'could be', probably Javascript), but in most languages (including Javascript) a substring function 'starts at' the position of the first parameter, and then 'ends at' that position plus the second parameter.  So when your second parameter is 'the position of the first space - 1', you can substitute 'the position of the first space - 1' with the number 13.  Thus, you're saying 'get a substring by starting one after the position of the first @ character i.e. position 6 in a zero-based system.  Then return me the next 13 characters.'

In other words, you seem to be trying to say 'give me the characters between position 6 and position 12 (inclusive)', but you're really saying 'give me the characters between position 6 and position 18 (inclusive)'.

This is

y o u r n a m e   h   i  s   n

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  11 12  13

(For some reason I can't get my spaces and newlines to get preserved in this answer; but if you count the letters in 'yourname hisn' it should make sense :) )

This is why you could use Neophyte's code so long as you can presume what the string would be.  To expand on Neophyte's answer, here's the code I would use (in the true branch of the conditional - you could also probably rename the variables based on this logic, etc.):

nameToSearch = rawName.substr(rawName.indexOf('@') + 1;

var nameFromNameToSearch = nameToSearch.substr(nameToSearch.indexof(' ') - 1;

nameFromNameToSearch would contain the string you're looking for.  I haven't completely tested this code, but I hope it 'conceptually' gives you the answer you're looking for.  Also, 'conceptually', it should work whether there are more than one '@' sign, etc.

P.S. In that first 'rawName.substr' I'm not giving a second parameter, which in Javascript et al. effectively says 'start at the first position and give me every character up to the end of the string'.